# Access variables in self.method in ruby script

Tags: ruby

I am very new to ruby. I am facing issue in getting the variable value in `self.method`

My ruby class/script look like this:

```
class A1
  def initialize
    @myUtil = MyUtil.new log
    @test_hash = @myUtil.loadPropertiesFile(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/my-tests.properties')
  end

  def self.testCases
    tests = {}

    @test_hash.each do |k, v|
        puts "#{k}"
    end

    tests
  end

  def launch test, testbed, h = {}

    @test_hash.each do |k, v|
        puts "#{k}"
    end

  end
end
```

I am able to print value in `@test_hash` in launch method but not in `self.testCases`. Where I am making the mistake?

Comment: Your code looks overly convoluted. What is it supposed to do? Or are you just trying to figure out how classes work in Ruby?

Comment: Looks like someone's done too much time in Perl. Watch out for global variables like `$test_hash`, and if you do declare them, refer to them consistently. There's no `$` vs `@` switching here.

Answer (score 3):

I see a few errors in your code.

- In your initialize method, you created a global variable `$test_hash`, anytime you put a `$` in front of a variable, it becomes available everything. That is not something you want to do in this case. An instance variable would work best for you in this case.
- Your `testCases` method is a class method, which means you can call it without creating a new instance of the class, ie `A1.new`. So you call the method like `A1.testCases` (Ruby uses snake case for method names, `test_cases`, just fyi). You initializes the `test_hash` variable in the `initialize` method, which does not automatically gets call until you create a new instance of the class. Therefore, `test_hash` does not exist when you simply run 'A1.testCases`.
- for the line `puts "#{k}"` is not good practice. `puts` stands for put string, and it will automatically convert the variable into a string. You should use `puts k`. the `#{}` is meant for string interpolation. Such as "Hi, my name is #{name}, and I am #{age} years old."

Here's how I would do this. I replaced the `test_hash` with a simple hash for testing purposes.

```
class A1
  def initialize
    @test_hash = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5}
  end

  def testCases
    @test_hash.each do |k, v|
        puts k
    end
  end
end
```

Now, you create a new instance of `A1` and call the `testCases` method (now an instance method, instead of a class method)

```
A1.new.testCases
```

Comment: Also confusing is `tests` being created in the method and never used, just returns an empty hash for no apparent reason. Also `"#{k}"` is a bad habit to get into. Just `puts k`, conversion is done automatically.

Comment: Hey, @davidhu2000, Your modification works. Actually my question was how I can use "@test_hash" variable which is in initialize method in "self.someMethod"?

Comment: I don't believe you can. The initialize method creates an instance variable for the instance of the class. You need to create a class instance variable, so you will need to create the `@test_hash` in the `self.testCases` method.

Answer (score 2):

The hard part is to understand, that in Ruby classes are also object. So `a1 = A1.new` is an object and `A1` is also an object.

By using `@` inside `initialize`, you create an instance variable belonging to `a1 = A1.new` object.

By using `@` inside `self.testCases` method, you create instance variable belonging to `A1` object.